# Always using displaystyle only for \lim

Tags: displaystyle

My question is a short one: I would like `\lim` to always be displayed inline using the  `\displaystyle` mode.

Comment: `\let\svlim\lim\def\lim{\displaystyle\svlim}`

Comment: why? This messes up line spacing

Comment: I know but for undergraduate student, it is better to see limits in `\displaystyle` format.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can you post this as an answer with a few explanations so as to accept it ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Not unless you want the entire expression to be in displaystyle.

Comment: @projetmbc, you'd be better to do as egreg says:-)

Comment: Unless you wanted the complete inline expression in `\displaystyle`, I too would select egreg's answer

Comment: @daleif @projetmbc: line spacing can be taken care of in most cases writing `usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.06}` in the preamble. The value 1.06 foor the stretch is of course a matter of taste.

Comment: @Bernard, did you actually test that? you have to go much much higher

Comment: @daleif: Well – yes. Of course it depends on what you have to write under  "lim". But as long as it's something as `x \to a`, it's OK. I use it rather commonly, e.g. for medium sized fraction from `nccmath`. Generally speaking, I find the default line spacing is too tight any way, and I use a stretcj between 1.05 and  1.1, depending on the font.@daleif

Comment: I still think it is a really bad choice, and not something that should be generally given as *good* advise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't want `\displaystyle`, but `\limits` after `\lim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\lim}{\limits}{}{}

\begin{document}
Here's a limit: $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, students can learn how to properly read symbols; I feel it wrong to attach too much to symbols, which are mainly *conventions* and not laws cast in stone.

Comment: We sometimes see teachers using `$\sum\limits...$` because apparently their students does not recognize a sum unless the limits are above and below. In a similar category they do not use `\exp` as their students does not know it is the same at `e^{...}`, so we'll see stuff like `e^{\int ....}` ...

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for this solution that uses less vertical space. :-) You're totally right for the conventions but my bachelor student are not corrected by me so I have to follow some recommandations.