# Is there a way to change the text size of \displaystyle?

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I know you can apply different font sizes in math mode such as `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.  What I am looking for is a way to get that "size" but still have the "style" of `\displaystyle`.

Specifically I am wanting to put limits in the numerator and denominator of a fraction, and the `\displaystyle` makes the expressions nearly overrun the fraction bar.  Here's the code I am using...

```
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g},$ provided $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g\ne0.$
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you want, and it would be easier if the example was a complete document so could test, but probably remove all the `\displaystyle` and use `\lim\limits_{...`

Comment: see also top answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161073/always-using-displaystyle-only-for-lim

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

You have

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g},$ provided $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g\ne0.$

However it should be (compare the final dot):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g},$ provided $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g\ne0$.

You want to either


$\lim_{x\to c}\limits\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\textstyle\lim_{x\to c}\limits f}{\strut\textstyle\lim_{x\to c}\limits g},$ provided $\lim_{x\to c}\limits g\ne0$.

or:


$\lim_{x\to c}\limits\left(\frac fg\right)=\frac{\lim_{x\to c}\limits f}{\lim_{x\to c}\limits g},$ provided $\lim_{x\to c}\limits g\ne0$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \limits was the way to go for me. Regarding your first comment, I see no difference.

Comment: @JohnMolokach If the dot end a sentence it should be after the dollar sign. In this case there are no differences in the result, but `$something$.` shows the inner logic of a document.