# How to put left aligned equation inside algorithmic

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, algorithms

I have a one-line equation that I want to use just like a statement in `algorithmic`. I tried with `flalign` and the equation still goes into the center. Could you please tell me how to fix that? Here is my MWE:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
   \State
    \begin{flalign}
    E_i &= \arg\!\max_{E\in \mathcal{E}} F(E)
    \end{flalign}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The reason I want to use equation instead of simple math mode is that I want `{E\in \mathcal{E}` to be properly under argmax, rather than a subscript. So if there is a way to do that, I'm happy with the simple `$` instead of equation.

Comment: Do you need the equation to be numbered?

Comment: @Werner: No I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use `\displaystyle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5764) to force content to be set similar to display math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5223/5764

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State $\displaystyle E_i = \argmax_{E \in \mathcal{E}} F(E)$
  \State $E_i = \argmax_{E \in \mathcal{E}} F(E)$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Related: [Always using `\displaystyle` only for `\lim`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161073/5764)